# Arbitrary type transformations of functor arguments and results

Tags: c++, c++11, functor, template-meta-programming

I have a class something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct operation {
    typedef T result_type;
    typedef ::std::shared_ptr<operation<T> > ptr_t;
};
```

I have a functor that would match this `::std::function` type:

```
::std::function<int(double, ::std::string)>
```

I want to create a functor that has a signature something like this:

```
operation<int>::ptr_t a_func(operation<double>::ptr_t, operation< ::std::string>::ptr_t);
```

I want to do this in an automated fashion so I can create a similar functor for any given `::std::function` type.

Lastly, I would like to put this wrinkle in. This:

```
::std::function<int(operation<double>::ptr_t, ::std::string)>
```

should result in this:

```
operation<int>::ptr_t a_func(operation<double>::ptr_t, operation< ::std::string>::ptr_t);
```

Because if a functor already accepts an `operation<T>::ptr_t` that means it understands what they are and is willing to deal with their asynchronous nature itself.

How would I do this? I have a naive and partially working attempt here:

```
template <typename argtype>
struct transform_type {
   typedef typename operation<argtype>::ptr_t type;
};

template <typename ResultType, typename... ArgTypes>
::std::function<typename transform_type<ResultType>::type(typename transform_type<ArgTypes...>::type)>
make_function(::std::function<ResultType(ArgTypes...)>)
{
   return nullptr;
}
```

It doesn't detect arguments that are already of type `std::shared_ptr<operation<T> >` though. And this specialization of transform_type fails to compile:

```
template <typename argtype>
struct transform_type<typename operation<argtype>::ptr_t>
{
   typedef typename stub_op<argtype>::ptr_t type;
};
```

Comment: What is the `operation` struct for? What do you hope to achieve with `ptr_t`? Your `typedef` seems problematic.

Comment: @devil: `operation` in the final version will represent a deferred asynchronous operation. It has no blocking methods for retrieving the result, but instead will notify dependents (things that care about the result) that one is available through a callback mechanism. The wrapping function will call the wrapped function once all the arguments become available.

Comment: `::std::function<int(operation<double>::ptr_t, ::std::string)>` this line, do you mean `::std::function<int(double, ::std::string)>`?

Comment: also `typedef ::std::shared_ptr<operation<T> >::ptr_t;` in the `operation` definition should be `typedef ::std::shared_ptr<operation<T> > ptr_t;`??

Comment: @user2k5: No to the first, yes to the second. Oops. Fixing it now.

Comment: oh, that means if it is already in `operation<double>::ptr_t` type, then do not do the transform, but it is not, then do the transform to `operation<double>::ptr_t`. Is this what you want?

Comment: @user2k5: Yes, exactly. If it's already an `operation<T>::ptr_t` type, then that means the function is aware of how they work and can handle their asynchronous nature itself.

Comment: This is not doable unless you forbid explicit specializations of `operation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured it out with [R. Martinho Fernandez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes)'s help:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_op_ptr {
 private:
   // Returns false_type, which has a ::value that is false.
   template <class AT>
   static constexpr std::false_type is_it_a_ptr(...);

   // Returns true_type (if enable_if allows it to exist).
   template <class AT>
   static constexpr typename ::std::enable_if<
      ::std::is_same<
         AT,
         typename operation<typename AT::element_type::result_type>::ptr_t>::value,
      std::true_type>::type  // note the true_type return
   is_it_a_ptr(int); // no definition needed

 public:
   // do everything unevaluated
   static constexpr bool value = decltype(is_it_a_ptr<T>(0))::value;
};

template <typename T>
struct transform_type
   : ::std::conditional< is_op_ptr<T>::value, T, typename operation<T>::ptr_t>
{
};
```

This also allows me to query whether or not a type will be transformed in the construction of the wrapper function.

Comment: This could be accomplished a _lot_ easier by way of a few template specializations IMO.

Comment: @ildjarn: Please, tell me what they are. I'm all ears. I asked this question because I only barely know what I'm doing. :-)

Comment: The problem is that while I'm (hopefully) quite aware of the supported _semantics_ of variadic templates, I only roughly know their syntax, as I don't keep around up-to-date copies of Clang and GCC. Consequently any answers  I would give regarding them would probably full of syntax errors. I'll try to grab a recent GCC build tomorrow and post a compilable implementation.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thank you! It would be greatly appreciated. Partly because I think I'd learn something. :-)

Comment: `*(reinterpret_cast<argtype *>(0))` looks like `std::declval<argype&>()` to me :)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: On gcc 4.7 `::std::declval<T>()` is not a `constexpr`. :-/

Comment: @Omnifarious So? You don't need `constexpr` for use in `decltype`, because it doesn't evaluate its argument. For  that matter, `reinterpret_cast` isn't `constexpr` either.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: In a different context it matters, and if `reinterpret_cast` isn't `constexpr` then I'm apparently relying on a compiler bug. :-/

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I updated my answer to show why the `constexpr`ness of it matters.

Comment: Ohhh. Don't do it like that. Use `true_type`, `false_type` and `decltype`, like this: http://ideone.com/w8csA, for example.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Ahh, yes, that looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<template<typename...> class F, typename Sig>
struct transform;

template<template<typename...> class F, typename R, typename... A>
struct transform<F, R(A...)> {
    using type = typename F<R>::ptr_t(typename F<A>::ptr_t...);
};
```

Usage looks like:

```
template<typename Sig>
void foo(std::function<Sig> f)
{
    using transformed_type = typename transform<operation, Sig>::type;
    std::function<transformed_type> g;
}
```

As for the specialization to avoid transforming types that are already in the desired form:

```
template<typename T>
struct operation<std::shared_ptr<T>> {
    using ptr_t = std::shared_ptr<T>;
    using result_type = ptr_t; // Or perhaps this needs to be T, you haven't said
};
```

Comment: One possible fly, it would be possible to have an `operation< ::std::shared_ptr<operation<int> > >`. With that specialization of `operation <T>` I'm not sure that could happen.

Comment: If `operation< ::std::shared_ptr<operation<int> > >::ptr_t` is `::std::shared_ptr<operation<int> >` and not `std::shared_ptr< ::std::shared_ptr<operation<int> >>` then it's just not possible: you're trying to find the inverse of a non-injective function.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: `operation< ::std::shared_ptr<operation<int> > >::ptr_t` is `::std::shared_ptr< operation< ::std::shared_ptr<operation<int> > > >`.

Comment: In that case, this should work fine (and yeah, I got that type wrong :S).